# Validate email address using pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, email-validation

I have written the code for validating the email address using pyspark but getting invalid email address.

**Input Email Address**

```
alcaraz@lcc@uma.es
```

**Output getting**

```
lcc@ums.es
```

**Expected output**

```
"invalid email address"
```

**code tried**

```
df1 = df.withColumn(df.columns[0], regexp_replace(lower(df.columns[0]), "^a-zA-Z0-9@\._\-| ", ""))
    extract_expr = expr(
        "regexp_extract_all(emails, '(\\\w+([\\\.-]?\\\w+)*@\\[A-Za-z\-\.]+([\\\.-]?\\\w+)*(\\\.\\\w{2,3})+)', 0)")

    df2 = df1.withColumn(df.columns[0], extract_expr) \
        .select(df.columns[0])
```

Comment: this may help : [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous "solutions" to be found for a definitive RE that ensures conformance with RFC5322. Here's the one I use. It may not match 100% of cases.

```
import re

expr = r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{| }~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_‘{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
p = re.compile(expr)

for ema in ['boris@gov.uk', 'alcaraz@lcc@uma.es']:
    v = 'valid' if p.match(ema) else 'invalid'
    print(f'{ema} is {v}')
```

Comment: `jeremy-@gmail.com` doesn't fit your regex However, it's quite simple and a valid email.